# How does promise.all handle multiple API calls when one of them fails?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I had a question on how `promise.all` handles rejection.

Let's say we have the following command

```
await Promise.all([
  server1.logMessage(),
  server2.logMessage()
])
```

And let's say server1 takes 2secs to log and server2 takes 5secs to log.

And what happens if the `server1.logMessage()` returns a error in 1 sec. Can we be sure that server2 will at least log the message even though the resultant promise from `promise.all` is rejected?

Or do i need to use `Promise.allSettled`?

Comment: since `server2.logMessage()` is executed immediately, then there's no fear of it not running

Comment: @Bravo Yes it will run but since server2 takes 5 sec.  Does the api call being done get canceled in the middle after the 1st API call fails

Comment: Promise.all doesn't effect the Promises it is waiting for ... it can't delve into server2.logMessage and stop it from running, since it is waiting for the promise that function has returned - that function is done, finished, before Promise.all can even start doing its thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your promises look to be independent. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
const prom1 = server1.logMessage();
const prom2 = server2.logMessage();
await Promise.all([prom1, prom2])
```

All the `Promise.all` does is adjust the flow of the program *in that block* - it doesn't affect what either `logMessage` may or may not do. If one `logMessage` happens to log a message, or if it happens to error instead, that'll have no effect on what the other `logMessage` does.

Comment: So we can be sure even if the first promise gets rejected, the 2nd API call won't get cancelled and the 2nd API call will run entirely?

Comment: Yes, unless the servers' APIs happen to depend on each other in some way